# What does renderViewHelper do in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

Trivial, but I swear I cannot find the information anywhere.

```
<?php $username = $this->form->username ?>
<?php echo $username->renderViewHelper() ?>
```

What does renderViewHelper() do here?

Comment: Checked this site: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html . What is your question by the way? Either it will make it to wiki or may result in 10 votedowns... Can you please be clear?

Comment: there you go, code example, clear enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

at times, you may want to use Zend_Form with the existing markup in the view, for example consider the below markup that is to be found in view file.

```
<form method="<?php echo $form->getMethod() ?>" action="<?php echo $form->getAction()?>">
    <div id="elements">
        <?php echo $form->element1->renderLabel() . $form->element1->renderViewHelper() ?>
        <?php echo $form->element2->renderLabel() . $form->element2->renderViewHelper() ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

the below syntax

```
$form->element1->renderLabel()
```

will fetch only the label tag. no fancy wrapper tags or anything. the same goes to

```
$form->element1->renderViewHelper()
```

this will only fetch the input (or whatever specified) element tag. so that you can embed the form with your own existing markup instead of allowing `zend_form` to create markup by itself.

check this link for more information http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.form.decorators.individual.html

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It renders the form element, specifically the `viewHelper` decorator from the form element, which is the one that renders the element itself (without any additional markup).